# Find triangle angle knowing side length change and angle change

Tags: trigonometry

There is triangle A with angle $\alpha=x$ and adjacent size $a$, and triangle B with angle $\beta=x-20$ and adjacent size $b=2a$, so
\begin{align*}
cos(x)/cos(x-20)=1/2 \\
\end{align*}
How do I find $x$?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:
$$2\cos x=\cos(x-20^\circ)=\cos x\cos20^\circ+\sin x\sin 20^\circ$$

$$\tan x=\frac{2-\cos20^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}$$